# Terminology! What's a word that conveys "Software", "Firmware" and "Hardware" combined?

Tags: terminology

Examples of things that are excluded: mechanical engineering, chemical engineering, industrial design.

I've struggled with

- Technology
- Hi Tech
- Computer Science
- EE

But I can't come up with an overarching term that is generally understood by everyone that means all of SW, FW and HW combined. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming at all

Comment: The term is computerware.  

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/computerware

Answer (score 1):

How about "System"?

Comment: By it's very definition, I have to agree that 'System' is the right word to start with. Now, the trick is finding a suitable adjective: Vertical System (as JOTN suggests); Digital System (digital covers every aspect of software, firmware, and hardware); Technology System.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical solution/system maybe.  Turnkey works too, but I tend to think of that as also meaning "drop in and go" while a vertical solution may still require a lot of implementation effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you're speaking relative to a particular product or project, I think you're looking for some variant on "stack" or "platform". The technology stack, the project stack, etc. If you're looking for a word that generally indicates the entire sphere of hardware, firmware, and software technology, I think you're better off listing them out like that. If you're free to editorialize, you might speak of the things they have in common, like bits & bytes or circuits & logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

**Computerware**

*Noun*

All hardware and software components of a computer system.

- The StrawRaspBananaBerry pie mini computer is a fully open source
  device as all computerware is under a GPL 2.0 license.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=computerware

Answer (score 0):

"Box"? ;-P

Could it not be "system"? Or "device" or something similar?

Comment: I think Box, System and Device will mean something entirely different from what I want it to mean without explaining. You don't think?

Answer (score 0):

Iphone ? just kidding 
 The proper term for an end to end solution is "turnkey solution". I guess that is what you are looking for a representation of a *Complete* Solution.

Comment: No, not turnkey. For example, mechanical engineering is excluded.

Comment: Firmware is just software (albeit generally used for embedded chips software) ... so what you need is basically software + hardware